Apex-Defined Class not showing in ScreenFlow or Funky Design?
Considering the code below:
I'm passing an Account...the List seems required even though there is only one Account...
The result is a list of my custom object "ServiceInfo".
When I attempt to create a ApexAction in my screen flow below:
2 output variables display independently as strings serviceid and servicetext....so thats not right.
It should be a list of ServiceInfo objects.
Then I trying returning a List of the List "bulkification at play?!?" and correctly I get one complex object that I attempt to map to my custom apex class "ServiceInfo"
But I am unable to find my custom class in the dropdown menu for mapping?!
What am I doing wrong?!  I feel like I'm missing something?
global class ServicesClient { 
    global class ServiceInfo {
        @InvocableVariable @AuraEnabled
        public String serviceID;
        
        @InvocableVariable @AuraEnabled
        public String serviceText;
        
        public ServiceInfo(String serviceId, String serviceText) {
            this.serviceId = serviceId;
            this.serviceText = serviceText;       
        }
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='GetActiveCustomerServices' description='Fetch services for a given customer ID')
    public static List<ServiceInfo> GetActiveCustomerServices(List<Account> accounts) { 
        // Flat list of ServiceInfo to return to Flow
        List<ServiceInfo> servicesList = new List<ServiceInfo>();
         
        // For each account, create a list of services
        for (Account acc : accounts) {
            System.debug('id is: ' + acc.Account_Number__c);
            
            String customerId = acc.Account_Number__c;
            
            try {
                Http http = new Http();
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

                // Set the endpoint URL (including the customer_id query parameter)
                String endpoint = 'https://example/Services?search.customer_id=' + customerId;
                request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
                request.setMethod('GET');
                
                // Set the headers
                request.setHeader('accept', 'application/json');
                request.setHeader('authorization', 'Basic *');  
                
                // Send the request
                HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
                
                // Check the response status
                if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    Map<String, Object> parsedResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

                    // Check if the response is OK
                    Boolean ok = (Boolean) parsedResponse.get('ok');
                    if (ok) {
                        List<Object> records = (List<Object>) parsedResponse.get('records'); // Access the records array

                        for (Object recordObj : records) {
                            // Cast the recordObj to Map<String, Object>
                            Map<String, Object> record = (Map<String, Object>) recordObj;

                            // Extract the phone number and service/package details
                            String tnnumber = (String) record.get('number');  
                            String packageid = String.valueOf((Integer) record.get('package_id'));
                            String serviceid = String.valueOf((Integer) record.get('service_id'));
                             
                            // Log each service's details
                            System.debug('Phone Number: ' + tnnumber);
                            
                            // Fetch the package description using a second API call
                            Http httpPackage = new Http();
                            HttpRequest requestPackage = new HttpRequest();
                            String endpointPackage = 'https://Example' + packageid;
                            requestPackage.setEndpoint(endpointPackage);
                            requestPackage.setMethod('GET');
                            
                            // Set the headers
                            requestPackage.setHeader('accept', 'application/json');
                            requestPackage.setHeader('authorization', 'Basic *');  // Use Named Credentials in production
                            
                            // Send the request to get package details
                            HttpResponse responsePackage = httpPackage.send(requestPackage);
                            
                            if (responsePackage.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                                Map<String, Object> parsedResponsePackage = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(responsePackage.getBody());
                                servicesList.add(new ServiceInfo(serviceid, tnnumber + ': ' + parsedResponsePackage.get('description')));
                            } else {
                                servicesList.add(new ServiceInfo(serviceid, tnnumber + ': NA'));    
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.debug('Response indicates failure: ' + response.getBody());
                    }
                } else {
                    System.debug('Error: ' + response.getStatus());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        System.debug('DrumRoll ' + servicesList);
        return servicesList; // Now a flat list of ServiceInfo objects
    }
}


What's the goal here?  pass in an Account and get back a ServiceInfo object?  Or pass in a list of accounts and get back a list of serviceinfo objects?  Please edit your question with updated info

@NickC i updated my question....thanks for your help!

This is pretty well covered in the documentation. Invocable methods are flow bulkified. If you want to accept or return lists of values, you will need to either use lists of lists or list of apex class containing lists of values.
